# Django: Obtaining the absolute URL without access to a request object

Tags: python, django, django-signals, django-settings

I have a model like the one below. When an instance is created, I want to send out an e-mail to an interested party:

```
class TrainStop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    notify_email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)

def new_stop_created(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):

    # Only for new stops
    if not created or instance.id is None: return

    # Send the status link
    if instance.notify_email:
        send_mail(
            subject='Stop submitted: %s' % instance.name,
            message='Check status: %s' % reverse('stop_status', kwargs={'status_id':str(instance.id),}),
            from_email='admin@example.com',
            recipient_list=[instance.notify_email,]
        )
signals.post_save.connect(new_stop_created, sender=TrainStop)
```

However, the `reverse` call only returns the path portion of the URL. Example: `/stops/9/status/`. I need a complete URL like `http://example.com/stops/9/status/`. How would I go about retrieving the hostname and port (for test instances that do not use port 80) of the current website?

My initial thought was to make this available via a variable in `settings.py` that I could then access as needed. However, thought someone might have a more robust suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's the sites framework, as yedpodtrzitko mentioned, but, as you mentioned, it's very much a manual setup.

There's requiring a setting in settings.py, but it's only slightly less manual than setting up sites.  (It can handle multiple domains, just as well as sites and the `SITE_ID` setting can).

There's an idea for [replacing get_absolute_url](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ReplacingGetAbsoluteUrl), that would make stuff like this easier, though I think its implementation suffers from the same problem (how to get the domain, scheme [http vs https], etc).

I've been toying with the idea of a middleware that examines incoming requests and constructs a "most likely domain" setting of some sort based on the frequency of the HTTP HOST header's value.  Or perhaps it could set this setting on each request individually, so you could always have the current domain to work with.  I haven't gotten to the point of seriously looking into it, but it's a thought.

Comment: "if they don't bother to set it, my app won't bother to work for them", but that's not helpful"?  How can you call stating a "requirement" to be "not helpful"?  It's an easy requirement to state.  It has to be put in the settings and that's the end of it.  Much of Django requires settings or it doesn't work.  Why should this app be "magical" and not require settings?  If you can't rely on the user, then, they're going to do something else to subvert the app also, aren't they?  Like alter the code.  Just state the required settings and be done with it.  Don't waffle.

Comment: This is true, but I meant more that it's not helpful to our current discussion towards a reliable domain detection method.  You're right, though, it's silly of me to say we "can't rely on the user" like that.

Comment: You can't detect the domain without the request, and `reverse` or `{%url%}`.  Anything else **requires** a setting.  It's simple.  No reason to waffle about it.  Require the setting and be done.

Comment: I've experimented with things that ended up pretty messy. Like saving the last used hostname. My hope was that someone figured out a more elegant solution that could provide the hostname based on the web server settings. Thank you @eternicode and @s.lott

Answer (score 4):

For getting current site there's object Site:

> If you don’t have access to the request object, you can use the
>   get_current() method of the Site model’s manager. You should then
>   ensure that your settings file does contain the SITE_ID setting. This
>   example is equivalent to the previous one:
>
> ```
> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>
> def my_function_without_request():
>     current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
>     if current_site.domain == 'foo.com':
>         # Do something
>         pass
>     else:
>         # Do something else.
>         pass
> ```

More info: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/

Comment: I currently don't use the sites framework. It seems like it'll be more work than what it's worth just to obtain the current domain--which has to be manually configured anyway. Thank you though.

Comment: I'm confused. This is precisely what the sites framework is for, and it gives you the ability to set this information once and have it available everywhere. It's also much easier to edit when it's in the DB than, as you suggested, in the settings file. So what, exactly, is the problem?

Comment: From the sites documentation: "Use it if your single Django installation powers more than one site and you need to differentiate between those sites in some way.". This is not a project with multiple websites so imho, implementing a model to store this data is overkill for my situation.