# Reversing urls in Django / Celery

Tags: django, celery

I have been asked to send an email on friday with a list of projects matching a set of conditions. The database front end is written in Django and its an in house application. I would like to link to the admin page of the project in the email.

On my development machine I am trying

```
reverse("admin:index")
```

and I notice that it is only returning

```
admin
```

from the Celery task, whereas in standard Django views this would return

```
127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
```

Is there a way around this? I would prefer not to hard code the start of the urls.

I have set up Celery as described in the "first steps with Django" tutorial, and have a

```
myproject/myproject/celery.py
```

file defining the app (alongside settings.py and urls.py) and

```
project/myapp/tasks.py
```

file with the actual tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reverse()` *always* returns a domain-relative url, i.e. `/admin/`. One option to increase portability is to use the [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sites/).

As you don't  have a `request` object in your Celery task, you have to explicitly set the `SITE_ID` in your settings and set the site's name and domain in your database. Then you can do:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
url = "%s%s" % (Site.objects.get_current().domain, reverse('admin:index'))
```

Comment: OK, I that makes sense. I guess using reverse in the Django application, then passing the URL to the task might work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Usually URLs in django are relative - i.e. the "127.0.0.1:8000" part you see when you hover the link comes from the fact that you are browsing the site from that location. Try looking at the href value of the URLs generated.

A simple solution to your problem is to concatenate the reverse output with the domain, i.e.

```
'http://example.com/'+reverse('admin:index')
```

Comment: I think its due to the celery worker being a different process from the Django application. I was trying to avoid the hard coding option, as moving servers may then become problematic - that's one of the main reasons for using reverse.

Comment: For this AFAIK you need a request object, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150258/django-obtaining-the-absolute-url-without-access-to-a-request-object for a discussion. You can also use the sites configuration: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/